# Can Brahmin's give daan to lower Varnas if it helps them?

Tags: varna, varnashrama, daana

What is the view of giving daan to lower communities? Can I give daan to communities that would use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiving Daana is only for Braahmanas. Specifically for the Brahmanas who have some relation to Shastras or Veda.

> अध्यापनमध्ययनं यजनं याजनं तथा । दानं प्रतिग्रहं चैव ब्राह्मणानामकल्पयत् ॥ १.८८॥
> Maanava Dharma Shastra 1.88

Teaching the Veda, learning the Veda, doing the Yajna, facilitating others to do the Yajna, giving charity, and receiving charity are the duties of a Brahmana.

For Kshatriyas and Vaishyas, their Dharma is only to GIVE Daana, and for Shudras, they neither give nor receive.

> Kshatriya: प्रजानां रक्षणं दानमिज्याऽध्ययनमेव च । विषयेष्वप्रसक्तिश्च क्षत्रियस्य समासतः
> ॥ १.८९॥

Protecting the people, giving Daana, performing the Yajna, learning the Veda, being detached from mental and physical objects is injuncted for the Kshatriya.

> Vaishya: पशूनां रक्षणं दानमिज्याऽध्ययनमेव च । वणिक्पथं कुसीदं च वैश्यस्य कृषिमेव च ॥
> ॥ १.९०॥

Protecting animals, giving Daana, doing Yajna, studying the veda, engaging in trade and business, lending and borrowing and agriculture are for the Vaishya.

> Shudra: एकमेव तु शूद्रस्य प्रभुः कर्म समादिशत् । एतेषामेव वर्णानां शुश्रूषामनसूयया ॥ १.९१॥

Only one thing has been injuncted for Shudras by the lord, it is to listen to, serve and follow these (3) Varnas.

Can you give Daana to beggars? Surely. But ultimately, they're suffering due to their own bad Karma. Rather than reducing their suffering, it's a superior use of wealth to promote the Veda by donating to a truthful and good quality Braahmana. Disabled/suffering/poor/starving/war stricken people should always be secondary.

Anything else would come under the realm of gits (which is also called Daana in Samskrta), which you can give to anyone you like, it's your money, afterall. But again, the first priority should be towards Veda, over your family or friend or some group you want to help.

Comment: Ahh I see thank you!

Comment: Yep, that's what I want to do give gifts to those who need it.

Comment: I can understand giving gifts to Brahminas especially those who need them and are serving a lifestyle in which a simple life is recommended so that they can focus on their learning. But, I also believe that if a Brahmin can survive on his own without help, then what use is there to give him, than those who already need it? For example, if I see a Brahmin in a forest who is hungry and needs food I would indeed feed him. Correct me where I am wrong if I am wrong.

Comment: @Haridasa Sure, giving money to a healthy Braahmana who is already wealthy isn't really the best. Afterall, authentic Braahmanaas aren't even meant to have food for more than 3 days at home and are supposed to be living in a minimalist hut. That type of dedicated and pure person, you will rarely find, and should definitely support in every way, regularly. If you cannot find someone like that, or close to that, then you should look into donating into Gurukulas, as they facilitated Veda study. Otherwise, donation to those who need it also produces good Karma, for sure, no matter what the Varna.